# swap text before and after a character

Tags: linux, windows-7, powershell, sed

I'm on Windows 7. I have a large text file `code.txt` with the following equalities

```
        oReservist.Role = Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 2)
        oReservist.Surname = Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 3)
        oReservist.Name = Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 4)
        ...
```

I want to change the first part of the equality by the second and the second by the first one. That is to say :

```
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 2) = oReservist.Role
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 3) = oReservist.Surname
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 4) = oReservist.Name 
        ...
```

How can I handle that ?

Until now that if I were on Linux I could have used `awk` with " = " as field separator, and simply turn around the fields.

```
awk -F " = " '{OFS=FS;print $2,$1}' file
```

or using sed:

```
sed 's/\(.*\) = \(.*\)/\2 = \1/' file
```

But it seems they are not recognised on Windows as I have the folowing error:

```
 PS C:\Users\alliasjb\Desktop> sed
Le terme « sed » n'est pas reconnu comme nom d'applet de commande, fonction, fichier de script ou programme exécutable.
 Vérifiez l'orthographe du nom, ou si un chemin d'accès existe, vérifiez que le chemin d'accès est correct et réessayez
```

Comment: Why are you asking for both linux and windows? If the sed solution doesn't work on windows, which seems to be your OS of choice, then remove the linux and sed tags.

Comment: If you are used to UNIX commands and find yourself working on Windows, then [Cygwin](https://cygwin.org), [Cmder](https://cmder.net/) or WSL (on Windows 10) are going to give you much solace. There you may `awk`, `sed` or `perl -pe 's/(.*) = (.*)/$2 = $1/' file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A powershell solution:

- working on all platforms
- keeping a possible indentation

---

```
(Get-Content .\code.txt) -replace '(\s*)(.*)( = )(.*)','$1$4$3$2'
```

To save to a(nother) file append

```
| Set-Content .\newcode.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download [Gawk for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm) and [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm).

I only tested `sed` in the Win10 command prompt:

```
C:\bin>more test.txt
oReservist.Role = Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 2)
oReservist.Surname = Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 3)
oReservist.Name = Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 4)

C:\bin>sed.exe "s/\(.*\) = \(.*\)/\2 = \1/" test.txt
Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 2) = oReservist.Role
Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 3) = oReservist.Surname
Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 4) = oReservist.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Another PowerShell way:

```
Import-Csv .\code.txt -Delimiter '=' -Header 'Left', 'Right' |
   %{ $_.Right + ' = ' + $_.Left } | out-file .\newcode.txt
```

If you need to presevere indentation, just modify the ForEach (%) block: `{ '   ' + $_.Right + ' = ' + $_.Left }`

Keith